# Fix animation of neighboring elements vue3 transition

Tags: vuejs3, vue-transitions

I am trying to figure how animate the button movement ...

when I check the checkbox, the textarea appears correctly with the transition ... and button sort of jumps down (which is fine with me for now)...

But the problem is, that when I uncheck the checkbox, the textarea disappears (within a transtion - all good) but after the transition is finished, the button JUMPS up :( it looks horrible.. how do I fix that?

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const showNote = ref(false);
const toggleCheckbox = () => {
  showNote.value = !showNote.value;
};
</script>

<template>
  <div class="add-note">
    <div class="flex align-items-center">
      <input type="checkbox" :checked="showNote" @click="toggleCheckbox"/>
      <label>Show note</label>
    </div>
    <Transition>
      <div v-if="showNote" class="note-area">
        <div class="form-item-full-width">
          <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Transition>
  </div>
  <Transition>
  <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-item-full-width">
      <button type="button">Submit data</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </Transition>
</template>


<style>
.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.v-enter-from,
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

here is an example in [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to avoid the "jump up" behavior, what you need to do is transitioning the max-heigth of the text area :

```
<style>
  .v-enter-active,
  .v-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    max-height: 100px;
  }

  .v-enter-from,
  .v-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
  }
</style>
```

See your example updated : [Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9VMFu2zAM/RVNpxao4wxdL54TbCt62A7dsPToi2LTjlpZMiTaSRDk30fJceKkXQ4GJPKJfE969I5/b5pJ1wJPeOpyKxtkDrBt5pmWdWMssh2zULI9K62pWcYJm/Gvmc50brQj9Mqsnw0Cm3ncTSmUg1vK91k0VaXgcQX529JsCHNzy2Zztss0O56cdEK1/vyn8wgV2dOXxj0vYkQbhLpRAoF2jKWF7FiuhHOzjIuiiDQdznjIXWRLBRsmlKx0JKmGi3LQCPYIJrjUTUuMtw0QPj9QzjhLwhoKig4EKfotVzJ/o9i5xIzHp4pKLEHNF3SIeWZp3AcO9GLiN6xfrNBOojT6dNrT7yJZnvcdBPmCkbAgRhIuNRtbB7VR2SoVrWWBqzM04RE26Ksw6fWt7y10EtbUR4va38MoYs3aV/3iSRjllw9TKpfGQ40xj5G4C6nxhdZT8j35pSm2/3nP69rSZYto9PCa/Y7yi3ZZS2SFQJHGffTdcwwrL+xotmA+h1vVO2/SRcE/kchRdnB3iCkQHb1KiPUmZwyPchMyoGLTyYNjIJz3t8/XYhOtQFYrTNjn6bTZhPjeNxz18dN33gXN0ME0Ipe4Tdj0g5KjgjRJQQC/4+hoPktZTV6d0TT7oRK53tSNVGB/N56vy3gy9KD5Usqsf4UY2raXHM54538Qf3U0DAkt/lhwYDsy7zFHdqkA+/TT4pn8M0rWpmgVoa8k/4IzqvUce9iPVhdEe4QLbH+GP5jU1Yt72iDQMxxEeaLhUgI+/NQer0g/0b2f3B8uc8/3/wCW/rcI)

Note: in this update I also remove the `Transition` tags wrapping the "Submit" button.

Comment: thx a lot .... would it be possible to wait for the textarea to disappear before the button slides up ? now it sort of slides up of the disappearing textarea

Comment: nevermind.. I got it :)